# Xamarin iOS - AddOverlays() only adding first polygon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/) tutorial for adding polygons onto a map in Xamarin. I am currently implementing the iOS section of this tutorial, but because I want to add multiple polygons to my map instead of the single polygon shown in the tutorial, I am using the `addOverlays()` function which takes in an array of `IMKOverlay` objects, instead of the `addOverlay()` function which takes 1 `IMKOverlay` object.

For some reason all of my polygons are being plotted at the same coordinates as my first polygon in my List, similar to an issue [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34908/mapping-multiple-circle-overlays) person had!

Here is my code:

```
void addPolygonsToMap()
        {
            overlayList = new List<IMKOverlay>();
            for (int i = 0; i < polygons.Count; i++)
            {

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[polygons[i].Count];

                    int index=0;
                    foreach (var position in polygons[i])
                    {
                        coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                        index++;
                    }
                    var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
                    overlayList.Add(blockOverlay);

            }
            IMKOverlay[] imko = overlayList.ToArray();
            nativeMap.AddOverlays(imko);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the code in `MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)` which is in the [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/#Customizing_the_Map). Just remove the `if` statement or remove the `polygonRenderer == null &&` in the `if` statement, like this:

```
        MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
        {

            if (!Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
            {         
                var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
                polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon)
                {
                    FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                    StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                    Alpha = 0.4f,
                    LineWidth = 9

                };
            }
            return polygonRenderer;
        }
```

Otherwise, it will always return the first `polygonRenderer` which is including your first coordinates group.

Comment: Hi @Barney Chambers, did my answer help you?